# BCP Fixed Width Import -> Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file?

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, fixed-width

I have some sensitive information that I need to import into SQL Server that is proving to be a challenge. I'm not sure what the original database that housed this information was, but I do know it is provided to us in a Unix fixed length text file with LF row terminator. I have two files: a small file that covers a month's worth of data, and a much larger file that covers 5 years worth of data. I have created a BCP format file and command that successfully imports and maps the data to my SQL Server table.

The 5 year data is supposedly in the same format, so I've used the same command and format file on the text file. It starts processing some records, but somewhere in the processing (after several thousand records), it throws Unexpected EOF encountered and I can see in the database some of the rows are mapped correctly according to the fixed lengths, but then something goes horribly wrong and screws up by inserting parts of data in columns they most definitely do not belong in. Is there a character that would cause BCP to mess up and terminate early?

```
BCP Command: BCP DBTemp.dbo.svc_data_temp in C:\Test\data2.txt -f C:\test\txt2.fmt -T -r "0x0A" -S "stageag,90000" -e log.rtf
```

Again, format file and command work perfectly for the the smaller data set, but something in the 5 year dataset is screwing up BCP.

Thanks in advance for the replies!

Comment: There isn't any way we can answer such a general question. You're going to have to use the tried and tested binary search, i.e. split your file in half and try and import each half, and continue until you find the offending data.

Comment: There can be non-printing characters in the data. Also, strings can be terminated by a nul. It might not be handled as expected by some tools. Try a tool that can search for special characters in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the offending characters in my fixed width file. Somehow whoever pulled the data originally (I don't have access to the source), escaped (or did not escape correctly) the double quotes in some of the text, resulting in some injection of extra spaces breaking the fixed width guidelines we were supposed to be following. After correcting the double quotes by hex editing the file, BCP was able to process all records using the format file without issue. I had used the -F and -L flags to examine certain rows of the data and to narrow it down to where I could visually compare the rows that were ok and the rows where the problems started to arise, which led me to discover the double quotes issue. Hope his helps for somebody else if they have an issue similar to this!